# Performant Way to List Foreign Keys for a MySQL Table?

Tags: mysql, performance

Is there a **performant** way to fetch the list of foreign keys assigned to a MySQL table?

Querying the information schema with

```
SELECT
    `column_name`, 
    `referenced_table_schema` AS foreign_db, 
    `referenced_table_name` AS foreign_table, 
    `referenced_column_name`  AS foreign_column 
FROM
    `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
WHERE
    `constraint_schema` = SCHEMA()
AND
    `table_name` = 'your-table-name-here'
AND
    `referenced_column_name` IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    `column_name`;
```

works, but is painfully slow on the versions of MySQL I've tried it with.  A bit of research turned up [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19588), which seems to indicate it's an ongoing issue without a clear solution.  The solutions which are hinted at require reconfiguring or recompiling mysql with a patch, which doesn't work for the project I'm working on.

I realize it's possible to issue the following

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

and get a string representation of a CREATE TABLE statement, which will include the foreign key constraints.  However, parsing this string seems like it would be fragile, and I don't have a large corpus of CREATE TABLE statements to test against. (if there's a standard bit of parsing code for this out there, I'd love some links)

I also realize I can list the indexes with the following

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

The list of indexes will include the foreign keys, but there doesn't appear to be a way to determine which of the indexes are foreign keys, and which are "regular" MySQL indexes.  Again, some cross referencing with the SHOW CREATE table information could help here, but that brings us back to fragile string parsing.

Any help, or even links to other smart discussions on the issue, would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why it would be fragile to write a simple parser for the foreign key part of a create table... create table syntax is clearly defined in the mysql docs...

Comment: I'm curious why performance would matter in a query like this. It's not that you want to investigate the database structure 50 times a second, and if you do, there's something horribly wrong with your application.

Comment: @Zak It's a philosophical thing, but I suspect that's ultimately what I'll need to do. I'm wary of edge cases not covered in the docs, I'm wary of mysql versions whose SHOW CREATE TABLE syntax may return something back that's not valid syntax, and I'm there's no way to overcome that wariness without putting in the time first.

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm working on tools for programmers and database users, and having to wait two or three minutes for a query to finish would break flow.

Comment: I see. I haven't got much experience in this area, but there are admin tools that don't seem to have a problem with this. Doesn't PHPMyAdmin show you foreign keys, and if so, maybe you can sneak peek into their code.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yep, that's another valid option for research if Stack Overflow doesn't come through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SequelPro and Magento both utilize the SHOW CREATE TABLE query to load the foreign key information. Magento's implementation is the one I am going to reference since it's both a PHP based system and one that both of us are very familiar with. However, the following code snippets can be applied to any PHP based system.

The parsing is done in the `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::getForeignKeys()` method ([the code for this class can be found here](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php)) using a relatively simple RegEx:

```
    $createSql = $this->getCreateTable($tableName, $schemaName);

    // collect CONSTRAINT
    $regExp  = '#,\s+CONSTRAINT `([^`]*)` FOREIGN KEY \(`([^`]*)`\) '
        . 'REFERENCES (`[^`]*\.)?`([^`]*)` \(`([^`]*)`\)'
        . '( ON DELETE (RESTRICT|CASCADE|SET NULL|NO ACTION))?'
        . '( ON UPDATE (RESTRICT|CASCADE|SET NULL|NO ACTION))?#';
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all($regExp, $createSql, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $ddl[strtoupper($match[1])] = array(
            'FK_NAME'           => $match[1],
            'SCHEMA_NAME'       => $schemaName,
            'TABLE_NAME'        => $tableName,
            'COLUMN_NAME'       => $match[2],
            'REF_SHEMA_NAME'    => isset($match[3]) ? $match[3] : $schemaName,
            'REF_TABLE_NAME'    => $match[4],
            'REF_COLUMN_NAME'   => $match[5],
            'ON_DELETE'         => isset($match[6]) ? $match[7] : '',
            'ON_UPDATE'         => isset($match[8]) ? $match[9] : ''
        );
    }
```

In the doc block it describes the resulting array as follows:

```
    /**
     * The return value is an associative array keyed by the UPPERCASE foreign key,
     * as returned by the RDBMS.
     *
     * The value of each array element is an associative array
     * with the following keys:
     *
     * FK_NAME          => string; original foreign key name
     * SCHEMA_NAME      => string; name of database or schema
     * TABLE_NAME       => string;
     * COLUMN_NAME      => string; column name
     * REF_SCHEMA_NAME  => string; name of reference database or schema
     * REF_TABLE_NAME   => string; reference table name
     * REF_COLUMN_NAME  => string; reference column name
     * ON_DELETE        => string; action type on delete row
     * ON_UPDATE        => string; action type on update row
     */
```

I know it's not **exactly** what you were asking for since it's using the SHOW CREATE TABLE output, but based on my findings, it seems to be the generally accepted way of doing things.