# I'm not seeing a foreign key index that I created

Tags: mysql, magento, indexing

I've created a table with a unique index as well as a foreign index.  When I add the unique key I get a success response from MySQL.  Then, when I add the foreign key I also get a success response.

Here's the SQL for adding the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `rewards_customer_index_points` 
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY FK_CUSTOMER_INDEX_POINTS_CUSTOMER_ID(  `customer_id` ) 
REFERENCES  `customer_entity` (  `entity_id` ) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

However, I'm not seeing that foreign key on the table, so it seems like it's not being created successfully.  But it's definitely there, b/c the cascade works when I delete the referenced customer_entity record.

Why isn't it showing in my index list?  Both tables are InnoDB.

Here is the table structure and keys on the table:

```
mysql> explain rewards_customer_index_points;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type              | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                           |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| index_points_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| customer_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| status          | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| points_positive | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |  
| points_negative | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| updated_at      | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+


show index from rewards_customer_index_points;
+-------------------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                         | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment     | Index_comment |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| rewards_customer_index_points |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | index_points_id | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rewards_customer_index_points |          0 | idx_customer_id_status |            1 | customer_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rewards_customer_index_points |          0 | idx_customer_id_status |            2 | status          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Most likely, your table is not an InnoDB table. 

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960418/foreign-key-between-mysql-innodb-tables-not-working-why/8960483#8960483

Comment: Thanks Roland, sorry I was planning to include this in my initial post but forgot to, so I'm editing it now.  Both tables are, in fact, InnoDB.

Comment: Please do a SHOW CREATE TABLLE just to be sure if the foreign key is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MySQL` land a foreign key is not an index, and won't show up in the list of indexes.  MySQL's original vision didn't include foreign key table relationships, it only included per-table indexes to improve select performance improvements.

InnoDB was originally a third party "extension" (not sure of the right term in MySQL speak) that added less speedy, but more compliant tables that included foreign key relationships. Because they were never part of the original vision, they were never incorporated into the `show index` or `describe table` commands.

Checkout [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451054/performant-way-to-list-foreign-keys-for-a-mysql-table) for some ways to get a list of foreign keys on a table.  Your choices are a slow query to the `information_schema`, or parsing the results of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command.

Comment: I agree with almost all you say but in which land is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint the same as an index? If there is one land that these two concepts get mixed, that's MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

First, Foreign Key and Unique constraints are not indexes, they are contraints. But to effectively enforce such constraints most DBMS use indexes.

In MySQL, `UNIQUE KEY` and `UNIQUE INDEX` are the same thing in a table definition, they mean: add a index and a Unique constraint.

For Foreign Keys, situation is a bit different. In InnoDB engine, when you add a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, an index on the referencing columns is created, but only if an index doesn't already exist.

You had the `idx_customer_id_status` index which is a `(customer_id, status)` compound index and this index can be used for the Foreign key constraint. So, no additional index was created.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube!  I think that the index that gets created by the foreign key constraint has the same exact name as the constraint (which makes perfect sense really), but I think that was part of the reason I so quickly assumed that the foreign key constraint was definitely one and the same as an index.

Comment: No, from what you posted, no index exists on `customer_id` alone. The compounbd index is used for the FK.